# Installing SHOGUN toolbox on ubuntu to python3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shogun

I installed the packages from the ubuntu software centre for Shogun Toolbox (http://shogun-toolbox.org/new/41/)

However they have installed for python2 and I need them for python3. Is there any way I can specify to install for python3?

I tried following getting the source instructions on the website and a few other questions previously asked and they did not work for me. I am new to linux.

Comment: @Lafada your comment seems irrelevant!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a few CMake variables indicating the version of Python you want to use. At least, you need to set `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR`,  `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`, `PYTHON_LIBRARY`, and `PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH`.

For more context:

```
cmake -DPythonModular=ON \ 
      -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \ 
      -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/Python3.4m \
      -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1 \
      -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages ..
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you write the relevant parts of the link in your answer? That way your answer will still be useful even if the link changes.

Comment: Thank you. I extracted the relevant bit from the link and wrote it in the answer directly.